# What are the advantages and disadvantages of conducting non-isolated unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I created a simple project for conducting unit tests, here is the sample code:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetCountry_ShouldReturnAndorra()
        {
            // Arrange
            int countryId = 1;
            string requestUrl = baseUrl + "/Countries/" + countryId;

            // Act
            // GET : /api/v1/Locations/Countries/{countryId} 
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl); 

            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode, "Response StatusCode is not success");

            string value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Assert.IsNotNull(value);

            var country = DeserializeCountryResponse(value);
            Assert.AreEqual(country.data.Id, countryId);

            Assert.AreEqual(country.errors.Count, 0, 0, "Reponse contains errors");
        }
```

And this project depends on whether the API server is running and its dependencies (databases, etc.)

But the documentation says that this is not the best practice (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#characteristics-of-a-good-unit-test):

> **Characteristics of a good unit test**
>
> ...
>
> **Isolated.** Unit tests are standalone, can be run in isolation, and have no dependencies on any outside factors such as a file system or database.
>
> ...

So should you go this way or is there another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is an no it is not. It just is not a unit test - it is an integration test. It may use unit test "frameworks" - but it basically is not a unit test but an integration test.

There is NOTHING wrong with using a lot of integration tests and at parts you acutally NEED them - many of my test suites are having a VERY large part of integration tests because they do test interaction over a whole network stack including (possibly changing) third party libraries.

Just do not pretend they are unit tests and the isolation part is out of the window. This really is a "definition" problem. Unit tests are there to test smallish code parts. Whole API endpoints are not smallish code parts. They still must be tested.

Comment: Oh, I'm so stupid, mixed up the integration test with the unit test.
Then if call it an integration test, then I'm on the right way (does my code meet the standards of integration testing)?

Comment: @IbnAdam Did you read the definition of the several testing parts and what they should do and what not?

Comment: @SirRufo right now? yes

Comment: @IbnAdam Well, then I do not understand your question if it meets the standards of integration testing. Read this answer and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing#Testing_levels

Comment: @SirRufo thanks for the link to the article, but I want to know, if you look from the point of view of integration testing in C #, is my code correct or is there a different (more correct) way?

Comment: @IbnAdam There is nothing special for C# and integration testing - and what more do you need as is already written in this answer: **it is an integration test**

Comment: Thank you very much @ TomTom and you @ SirRufo for your useful answers, now I'll think more sensibly (in terms of testing) :)